# Get JSON with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to get this JSON in Android with Volley. How can I do that?

```
{ "post": [ { "title": "a", "content": "a", "mobile": "a", "imageurl": "a" }, { "title": "b", "content": "b", "mobile": "b", "imageurl": "b" } ], "banner": [ { "title": "c", "content": "c", "mobile": "c", "imageurl": "c" }, { "title": "d", "content": "d", "mobile": "d", "imageurl": "d" } ] }
```

This is my code in Java:

```
public void GetPost(JSONObject jsonObject, final onPostReceived onPostReceived) {
    String url = "";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


            Log.i(TAG, "onResponseGetPost: " + response.toString());
            try {
                // iwant to get all posts and banners 
                //for example 20 post
                // 2 banner

                List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<PostBanner> postBannerList = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONArray json = response.getJSONArray("banner");
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("post");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Post post = new Post();
                    PostBanner postBanner = new PostBanner();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    post.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("imageurl"));
                    post.setContent(jsonObject.getString("content"));
                    post.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                    post.setMobile(jsonObject.getString("mobile"));

                    postList.add(post);


                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    postBanner.setTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    postBanner.setContent(jsonObject1.getString("content"));
                    postBanner.setMobile(jsonObject1.getString("mobile"));
                    postBanner.setImageUrl(jsonObject1.getString("imageurl"));

                    postBannerList.add(postBanner);
                    onPostReceived.onReceived(postList, postBannerList);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         //log error
        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
}
```

What is the problem in this code? It get posts until banner length, but just one banner when I run the app. Why?

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Your JSON is Incorrect

Comment: You have to use nested loops when you parse the json.

Comment: what can i do?- intellij-amiya

Comment: this is right format of your json : {
  "post": [
    {
      "title": "a",
      "content": "a",
      "mobile": "a",
      "imageurl": "a"
    },
    {
      "title": "b",
      "content": "b",
      "mobile": "b",
      "imageurl": "b"
    }
  ],
  "banner": [
    {
      "title": "c",
      "content": "c",
      "mobile": "c",
      "imageurl": "c"
    },
    {
      "title": "d",
      "content": "d",
      "mobile": "d",
      "imageurl": "d"
    }
  ]
}  you can check it out in http://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: @Piyush wrong .Check here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: I checked it did not matter @Piyush

Comment: @ali what's your error?

Comment: i want to get all post but i get until banner length  @Piyush

Comment: @ali can you explain more?

Comment: @ali you want to get all banner with each post? is it?

Comment: problem is here `"imageurl":"d”` should be `"imageurl":"d"`

Comment: @Piyush see. i want to get post and banner  for example 20 post and 2 banner  but i get post until banner have data it means i get 2 posts

Comment: @ali first you need to move onPostReceived.onReceived(postList, postBannerList); out side of your for loop

Comment: your double inverted comma is special character not double inverted comma

Comment: @ali you should review your code first before posting, you are calling on onPostReceived method in for loop and obviously you will get one post

Comment: It will throw exception while parsing last data of banner

Comment: i move  onPostReceived.onReceived(postList, postBannerList); in out side of loop and  double inverted comma When i typing is wrong @Piyush thanks i check it

Comment: Was not true.  
That's true but I do not know what happened. @Piyush

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Post post = new Post();

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                post.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("imageurl"));
                post.setContent(jsonObject.getString("content"));
                post.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                post.setMobile(jsonObject.getString("mobile"));

                postList.add(post);

            }

       for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            PostBanner postBanner = new PostBanner();

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = json.getJSONObject(i);
                postBanner.setTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                postBanner.setContent(jsonObject1.getString("content"));
                postBanner.setMobile(jsonObject1.getString("mobile"));
                postBanner.setImageUrl(jsonObject1.getString("imageurl"));

                postBannerList.add(postBanner);
       }


       onPostReceived.onReceived(postList, postBannerList);
```

Comment: my post become true.but i receive 1 banner in android  @Piyush

Comment: post code is true.but now i get just last banner object @Piyush

Comment: please help me! @Piyush

Comment: @ali i created demo with your sample json and print the size of both list and  its 2 "D/TAG: POST: 2 Banner: 2".